# is good practice to include my modules in node_modules for make require search easy,if not why not?

Tags: node.js, express

is good practice to include my modules in node_modules for make require search easy,if not why not?

**Explanation:**

In  node.js cms calipso( https://github.com/cliftonc/calipso) 
their modules not inside node_modules: then the include the modules without auto option:

```
calipso = require(path.join(rootpath, 'lib/calipso'));
```

vs if it was inside node_modules:

```
calipso = require('calipso');
```

Comment: I prefer to keep a separated modules folder for my own modules, but then again I've only made two small projects so I'm not sure what best practice is, I just think it's not "right" to use non-vendor modules within the node_modules.

Answer (score -1):

`node_modules` is typically ignored in the version control (GIT, etc) and most of the developers assume that this folder contains only packages listed in the `package.json`. I can imagine the approach on updating the modules just by removing this folder completely and executing `npm install`. Considering these I would rather say that keeping own modules in `node_modules` is not consistent with the node.js workflow.

Update: this is assuming that "my modules" is actually just a set of files. If your modules are "npm" modules, that can be restored by executing "npm install" then this is completely fine to keep them in node_modules.

Comment: its ignored by git if you define it.

Comment: It is defined in 99% of the projects that have it.

Comment: but somebody define it right? i also in my project define it like that, but i pay the cost of search

Comment: What do you mean by paying the cost of search?